# Grails session attributes are not flushed between two applications

Tags: session, grails, cas, jasig

I have two separate Grails applications that use the [JASIG CAS Client Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/cas-client-plugin). When my applications run, different users can authenticate against my CAS server (using the client plugin).

Authentication aside, I use a Grails Filter for ***authorization*** in both applications. A user may be authenticated, but I want to make sure that only certain users can only access the appropriate application.

Everything works, except for the below scenario:

1. I successfully authenticate against the CAS server with username "jack" and I am authorized to use Application A.
2. I close Application A and sign out of CAS.
3. I successfully authenticate against the CAS server with username "jill", but I am not authorized to use the Application B because the username from the session is still "jack"

Do I need to flush the session at any point when my applications initiate?  If so, how can I do that?  Here is the code for my Filter:

```
import edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.CASFilter

class SecurityFilters {
    def filters = {
        loginCheck(controller: '*', action: '*') {
            before = {

                def username = session?.getAttribute(CASFilter.CAS_FILTER_USER)?.toLowerCase()

                if (username in grailsApplication.config.users) {
                    return true
                } else {
                    render view: '/invalid_user', model: [username: username]
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your logout remove the session attribute?

Comment: Right now I do not have a logout button within each application. Is that what I would need? If so, would it simply be a 'session.invalidate()'? What I don't like about that is that if the user just closes the window, without clicking "Logout", then the session would not be removed...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435602/cas-logout-and-cookies-elimination Maybe is this what's happening for you?